# Php Search Function Returning Error

Tags: php, search

Okay I have been taticling the creation of a search function for my site today and so far everything has been going fine I found a youtube tutorial that is really helping and I have put all the code into the search.php file.

But I am getting these errors maybe someone could explain them to me and possible help

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/34/9587634/html/MyDomain.Com/search.php on line 21

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/34/9587634/html/MyDomain.Com/search.php on line 25
```

And here is the code im using. I have tried searching and cant seem to find the problem

```
<html>
<?php
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
$query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each){
$i++; 

if ($i == 1)
$query .= "content LIKE '%$each%' ";
else
$query .= "OR content LIKE '%$each%' ";
}


include('config.php');


$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$FirstName = $row['FirstName'];

}

?>
</html>
```

All help is greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just try with the following example :**

```
<?php

if($_GET['k'])
{
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);

        foreach ($terms as $value) {

        if($value=='') $q.=""; else $q.="(`content-value` LIKE '%$value%' OR `content-value` LIKE '%$name%') ";

        if($q=="") $total=0;

    else
    {
        $search = "SELECT * FROM ".CONTENT." WHERE".$q;
        $search = str_replace('WHERE','WHERE ',$search);
        $search_res = mysql_query($search) or die("Search: ".$search.mysql_error());
        $total = mysql_num_rows($search_res);
    }
    }
}
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) rerurn FALSE if you query contain errors. So, you try execute query **mysql_query($query)** and mysql_query return FALSE(maybe). Function [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) expects one parameter and it must be a result of mysql_query() function. NOT BOOLIAN.

But $query is FALSE.

FALSE is BOOLIAN.